# setState doesnot change the state in floatingActionButton in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, state

This is my floating action button wrapped around with a couple of widgets. The problem is whenever I click on it, the isVisible property should have been changed to false and it should have been invisible but that doesnot happen. "Pressed undo" is printed in the console.

```
             Positioned(
                        left: 0,
                        bottom: 15,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Visibility(
                            visible: isVisible,
                            child: FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isVisible = false;
                                  print("pressed undo");
                                });
                              },
                              child: const Icon(Icons.undo_rounded),
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEC3F27),
                            ),
                            replacement: Container(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I have declared the isVisible variable here. p.s. The action button is invisible if I manually change the value of isVisible to false. There is a problem with setState.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it should work, I'm not sure why it does not work for you,
any erors in console?
you can still try something like this:

```
                Positioned(
                          left: 0,
                          bottom: 15,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                            child: isVisible
                                ? FloatingActionButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isVisible = false;
                                        print("pressed undo");
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: const Icon(Icons.undo_rounded),
                                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEC3F27),
                                  )
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Nope. This still didn't work. No errors on console. Nothing. I see no fault on the code. I am gonna go cry. :(